# Automatically packages are adding while doing npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, npm

I am facing a very weird issue with `npm`. I tried -

`npm install cookie-parser`

and the output is -

```
test@1.0.0 /home/techsolvr/Projects/nodeApp/test
`-- cookie-parser@1.4.0  extraneous

npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON test@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON test@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

But inside my `node_modules` folder following packages included -

1) cookie | 2) cookie-parser | 3) cookie-signature

So you can see 3 folders added instead of 1.

Let me know which setting I need to change ?

node -v => v5.1.0
npm -v  => 3.3.12

Same is the case with body-parser install, let me know if its ok...or something wrong with the configuration.

Comment: The cookie-parser module uses those as dependencies.

Comment: @Shinobi881 That is understandable ..but my query is it should be inside cookie-parser module rather than at the same level

Comment: Sometimes it's for modularity. For instance, they may each have their own bundling processes. But I'd test to see if they're needed there as well. `npm prune` or just uninstall them and see if it breaks stuff.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) cookie, and cookie-signature are dependencies of cookie-parser. Usually they would be installed in cookie-parser's node-modules directory but I suspect, that they should be kept even if cookie-parse is uninstalled?